# sox.core.SoxError: Stdout: Stderr: sox FAIL formats: ‘XXX': WAVE: RIFF header not found when dealing with voice files from wxrobot

Tags: voice, sox

I got `.wav` file from werobot through medie_id with url:"https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/media/get?access_token=%s&media_id=%s",

Then I use `sox` to convert the file to demanded:

```
 sox -D -V2 -t wav 
/tmp/knime_deepspeech_app/Dc3hVz0p5YqtsFyZ4lXzVfyIrAnee5wMz2N4.wav -b 16 -c 1 
/tmp/knime_deepspeech_app/nV2m5YeGhgeJSwMXhnOCnnLqatGEqS3YN1ar.wav highpass -2 
150.000000 0.707000q lowpass -2 6000.000000 0.707000q rate -h 16000.000000
```

Error Info below：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The format of voice from wxrobot is amr, we need to use "**ffmpeg -i {filePath_amr} -ar 16000 -ac 1 {filePath_wav}**" to convert file from amr to wav, then the sox command runs ok!